# Kotlin coroutines CalledFromWrongThreadException

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I'm trying to use Kotlin coroutines to make some heavy job runs in the background.

But I got this error message,

> 'android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the
>   original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.'

```
fun setList() {
    media_image_list.adapter = imageListAdapter
    ...

    launch {
        val images = getImages(galleryPath)
        imageListAdapter.setItems(images)
    }
}




suspend private fun getImages(): MutableList<Image> {
    val uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    ...
}
```

How to make it run in background correctly?

Comment: Could you try to run the Coroutine in `Unconfined` mode like this: `launch(Unconfined)`?

Comment: @s1m0nw1 It works, Do I need to use Unconfined if the job related with any UI works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest to address it in the following way:

First, explicitly offload your "heavy job" into background threads using `withContext` function like this:

```
// explicitly request it to be executed in bg thread
suspend private fun getImages(): MutableList<Image> = withContext(CommonPool) {
    val uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    ...
}
```

Then, always run the coroutines that touch the views or other UI objects in UI thread:

```
launch(UI) {
    val images = getImages(galleryPath)
    imageListAdapter.setItems(images)
}
```

Comment: Can I do just without 'run(CommonPool)'? Without that, it wouldn't run in background threads?

Comment: You omit `run(CommonPool)`, then your `getImages` code will run in UI thread. It is Ok if your `getImages` uses _asynchronous_ non-blocking APIs, but it is not Ok if it uses APIs that block a thread.